# I have a 6" insulated duct what size t should I use?

Tags: hvac

I would like to know ,do I use a 6" insulated duct to a 6" register?

Comment: There are also circular registers for walls depending on how the ductwork is configured.

Comment: Are you tapping into a 6' line and trying to add another register?

Answer (score 1):

A 6" duct should feed a 4x10 or 3x10 standard adjustable floor register. The round duct has a cross section area of about 30 sq. in. In a well designed duct layout there would not be excessive pressure at any register, so closing the adjustment vanes any amount should not be a problem.